# opensearchserver: cannot open files/links provided by the renderer (local links/files)

Tags: file, hyperlink, server, renderer, opensearch

I have a question in terms of the renderer:
My search query is running fine and gives prosper output.
But the links provided by the renderer, I mean the results of the search, are not working.
They simply lead nowhere… is there a solution for opening local links through the renderer?

Ps: local filesystem and smb crawler were used. Same problem…

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of a comment in the [official documentation](http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/faq/README.md):

In the renderer you can apply a regular expression on the URL to change it to something like file://.... This is done in tab "Fields" of the renderer. For IE for example, field URL Pattern should be ^smb://(.*) and URL replace should be file:///$1.

When using another browser please adapt this to the proper expected syntax.

However, by default, for security reasons, the Internet browsers do not allow opening a local file from an Internet web site.

This page give [few workarounds](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-file-url.html).

To solve this problem for Chrome and Firefox, you can install an extension that will allow this.

- [For Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/locallinks/)
- For [Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work)
- Another [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/?src=search) option
- About Internet Explorer you can find a [good explanation here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. The URL replacement was already done by us --> doesn't really help, because of all the used browsers. These workarounds you postet are also not suiteable for us, since they are not universal. Even if they seem to work (tried them too...). But here is another question, since we like OSS and want to get it run properly: Would it be possible to access or better to open our searched and found files, if they wouldn't be "local" anymore? I mean, if we would host them anywhere, so it would be http:// instead of file://?